# Undefined references when including boost library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to use boost's asio library, but I keep getting undefined references.  I'm on Dev-Cpp on Windows, which is using the G++ compiler.

I installed boost using the installer from boostpro computing for Boost 1.42.0 [[link](http://www.boostpro.com/download)].  Here is the code of the test program I am trying to make:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(void){
    std::cout << "Boost test." << std::endl;
}
```

My boost include headers are under `/include` and all the libs for boost are compiled and under `/lib` directly.  There seems to be some library that's not being included, but I do not know what is.  I've tried including a few likely ones but to no avail.

The kind of linker errors I'm getting are:

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
[Linker error] undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()' 
ld returned 1 exit status 
C:\Dev-Cpp\Projects\Boost Test\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [boostTest.exe] Error 1
```

I've been trying to get boost to work for a while and would really appreciate any help on the matter.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you linking to the boost library ? Including a header and linking to a library are 2 separate concepts.

Comment: I tried some linking in with libraries but I wasn't sure which ones.  I experimented with some likely ones, like the system and iostream libraries, but I got the same result every time.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem a few days ago when working with boost::asio. You need compile and  link with the boost::system library.

Comment: How did you do that?  I've tried linking all the boost_system and libboost_system libraries I found but I got the same results.

Comment: @alecRN: Check russoue's answer. Add `-lboost_system` to g++ arguments (to linker actually).

Answer (score 0):

You have to link to libboost_system.a and libboost_filesystem.a.

Answer (score 0):

I use netbeans so i typed '-lboost_system' in additional lines ! That was a mistake.

Additional lines are put before objects, and because of that i had the same error. Then i found out if i run from console and put -lboost_system at the VERY END everything works greate. At the end i found the right place to set in netbeans (in library not command section) and that field adds it at the end!

Remember, not only counts if you have the library in command ! THE POSITION does count :) Remember to put library at end and verify it :)

Work great:

```
g++.exe -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF async_client.o.d -o async_client.o async_client.cpp
g++.exe -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -o async_client async_client.o -lws2_32 -lboost_chrono -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

Doesn't work:

```
g++.exe -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF async_client.o.d -o async_client.o async_client.cpp
g++.exe -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -lws2_32 -lboost_chrono -lboost_system -lboost_thread -o async_client async_client.o
```

Comment: To reviewers from the "Late Answers" queue: this is a duplicate answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708894/boost-asio-installation-issue/12447535#12447535 I'm not sure how to handle this though.