# Boost.Asio installation issue

Tags: c++, boost-asio

i have already installed boost libraries with bjam install, but when i'm compiling programme:

```
#include boost/asio.hpp

int main()
{
 return 0;
}
```

such errors occur:

```
/tmp/ccVR3eeF.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
sda.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
sda.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
sda.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccVR3eeF.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
sda.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[boost::asio::error::get_system_category()]+0x5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccVR3eeF.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr_create(unsigned int&)':
sda.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail20posix_tss_ptr_createERj[boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr_create(unsigned int&)]+0x19): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/tmp/ccVR3eeF.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()':
sda.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_15task_io_serviceEE7contextEED2Ev[boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()]+0x15): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/tmp/ccVR3eeF.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::strand_service::strand_impl>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()':
sda.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_14strand_service11strand_implEE7contextEED2Ev[boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::strand_service::strand_impl>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()]+0x15): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what do i have to do? how can i build those libraries?

Answer (score 7):

Boost.Asio requires the Boost.System library as well; you need to add `-lboost_system` to your linker command line.

As you add features to your program, you might also need other parts of Boost, like Boost.Thread, Boost.Date_Time, and so on.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

I use netbeans so i typed '-lboost_system' in additional lines ! That was a mistake.

Additional lines are put before objects, and because of that i had the same error. Then i found out if i run from console and put -lboost_system at the VERY END everything works greate. At the end i found the right place to set in netbeans (in library not command section) and that field adds it at the end!

Remember, not only counts if you have the library in command ! THE POSITION does count :) Remember to put library at end and verify it :)

Work great:

```
g++.exe -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF async_client.o.d -o async_client.o async_client.cpp
g++.exe -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -o async_client async_client.o -lws2_32 -lboost_chrono -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

Doesn't work:

```
g++.exe -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF async_client.o.d -o async_client.o async_client.cpp
g++.exe -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -lws2_32 -lboost_chrono -lboost_system -lboost_thread -o async_client async_client.o
```

Comment: This answer is hard to read.  I'm not familiar enough to edit it myself.